# Router for nested resources in a "not usual" Ruby on Rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resources, routes

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I am trying to set nested resource routing to make it to work in a "not regular" RoR way.

In my `routes.rb` file I have

```
resources :articles do
  resources :categories, :only => [:index], :controller => 'articles/categories' # The related controller is Articles::CategoriesController
end
```

so that I can browse following URLs:

```
<my_site>/articles/1/categories
<my_site>/articles/2/categories
...
```

What I would to do is to access `new`, `edit` and `show` controller actions for categories by using the same `articles/categories` controller used for the nested resource stated above (that is, `Articles::CategoriesController`) and by accessing these URLs:

```
<my_site>/articles/categories/new
<my_site>/articles/categories/edit
<my_site>/articles/categories/1
<my_site>/articles/categories/2
...
```

**How can I do that? How I must code the router?**

---

Maybe I can do something by using the router `collection` method like this

```
resources :articles do
  collection do
   # match something here for the Articles::CategoriesController...
  end

  resources :categories, :only => [:index], :controller => 'articles/categories'
end
```

but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: do you want <my_site>/articles/2/categories/new or <my_site>/articles/categories/new. I am asking to verify that was a typo? :)

Comment: @Felix - I want access the `<my_site>/articles/categories/new` path and use the `Articles::CategoriesController` `new` action.

Comment: You can probably add a namespace for the <my_site>/articles/categories/new. It is explained here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: You can probably add a namespace for the <my_site>/articles/categories/new. It is explained here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing. In the sense define the namespaced url first and then the nested routes. In that way, I think all the routes you need will be accessible.

Comment: @Felix - I know, but I don't think that is what I would like to have in my router. Moreover, it will constrain me to keep the namespace stated before the `resources :articles` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real sure what you're trying to do with those routes, so I'm not quite sure how to answer your questions. If your intent is to be able to add a new category for a particular article, or edit all the categories for a particular article, you have to pass an ID for the article. If you're trying to create a new article and a new category all at once, you don't need `category` in the route, just the article and you can do something like `form_for([@article,@category])` in your form and use the `build` method in your controller. If you can clarify, I might be able to help you further (in other words, it's not hard to construct those routes -- but it depends on what you want to do with them.

Comment: I want access the `<my_site>/articles/categories/new` path and use the `Articles::CategoriesController` `new` action and so on for all other controller actions except for the `index` for which I would like to use the `<my_site>/articles/1/categories/` that I properly handle in the controller.